# KTable as input from topic with null keys

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm very new to Kafka Streams and encountered a problem.

I have two tables - one is for long-term data (**descriptions**) and the other is for live data (**live**). They have a common *id*.

And the idea is to store data from **descriptions** (presumably in KTable, keep latest description for each *id*) and when new messages appear in **live** - join with data from **descriptions** on corresponding *id* and send it further.

For simplicity let's just make all types String.

So the basic idea was like in every tutorial I've seen:

```
interface Processor {

        @Input("live")
        KStream<String, String> input();

        @Input("descriptions")
        KTable<String, String> input();

        @Output("output")
        KStream<String, String> output();
    }
```

And then:

```
    @StreamListener
    @SendTo("output")
    public KStream<String, String> process(
            @Input("live") KStream<String, String> live,
            @Input("descriptions") KTable<String, String> descriptions) {
        // ...
    }
```

The problem is that **descriptions** topic is not KTable-suitable (null keys, just messages).

So I can't use it as an input and I can't create any new intermediate topics for storing a valid stream out of this table (basically read-only).

I was searching for some sort of in-memory Binding destination, but to no avail.

The way I thought it could be possible is something like creating an **intermediate** output that just stores KTable in-memory or something and then using this **intermediate** as an input in **live** processing. Like:

```
    @StreamListener("descriptions")
    @SendTo("intermediate")
    public KTable<String, String> process(@Input("descriptions") KStream<String, String> descriptions) {
        // ...
    }
```

Hope it's possible with this Binding semantics.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. How can you "join" an event to a description without the description having a key - which description from the table should be bound to the event? How would it be selected?

Comment: @GaryRussell Exactly, so I want to consume this "unkeyed" stream and map it to a KTable **with** a key and this one is to be used for joining. Basically I need (or so I think) a way to persist an intermediate KTable so I can use as input further down the pipeline.

Comment: But how will you generate the key from a description?

Comment: @GaryRussell Something like (sorry for formatting):
`@StreamListener("descriptions")
    @Output("intermediate")
    public KTable<String, String> process(KStream<String, String> descriptions) {
        return descriptions
                .map((key, value) -> {
                    Pojo p = parseIntoPojo(value);
                    return new KeyValue<>(p.getId(), value);
                })
                .groupByKey()
                .reduce((v1, v2) -> v2);
    }`

If that's not possible, well, need to do it without the Binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to introduce an intermediate topic for storing the key/value by introducing an initial processor. Then use that stream as a table for the input in your regular processor. Here are some templates. I am using the new functional model in Spring Cloud Stream to write these processors.

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> processDescriptions() {

        return descriptions -> 
            descriptions.map((key, value) -> {
                Pojo p = parseIntoPojo(value);
                return new KeyValue<>(p.getId(), value);
            })
            .groupByKey()
            .reduce((v1, v2) -> v2)
            .toStream();
}

@Bean
public BiFunction<KStream<String, String>, KTable<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> realStream() {

    return (live, description) -> {

    }

}
```

The first processor receives the `description` as `KStream` and then enrich that with the key and then output as `KStream`. Now that this topic has both key and value, we can use this as a `KTable` in our next processor. The next processor is a `java.util.function.BiFunction` which receives two inputs and generate an output. The inputs are `KStream` and `KTable` respectively and the output is a `KStream`.

You can set destinations on them as below:

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=prorcessDescriptions;realStream

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processDescriptions-in-0.destinaion=description-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processDescriptions-out-0.destinaion=description-table-topic

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.realStream-in-0.destinaion=live-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.realStream-in-1.destinaion=description-table-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.realStream-out-0.destinaion=output
```

You can achieve the same results by using the `StreamListener` approach as well.

The downside of this approach is that you need to maintain an extra intermediate topic in Kafka, but if you really want it as a `KTable` and the underlying information is non-keyed, I don't think there are too many options here.

If you don't need the descriptions as a top-level `KTable`, you might be able to store this somehow in a state store and later query that store all within a single processor. I haven't tried that out, so you need to play around with that idea. Basically, you get two streams, live and descriptions

```
(live, descriptions) -> Reduce key/value for descriptions and keep that in a state store. 
Then, do the processing on live by joining with what is in the state store.
```

Kafka Streams allows various ways to accomplish things like that. Check their reference docs for more info.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did help! Thank you!

Comment: Note that `reduce()` won't handle tombstones correctly. If you want to convert/upsert a `KStream` into `KTable` you should use the `#toTable()` operator instead.